# ios - SocketMobile SocketScan Keyboard problems

Tags: ios, socketscan, socketmobile

I have implemented this scan `API` just recently and am running into some problems with keyboard. The bar code does not populate into the desired `UITextField object` unless I have that text field selected. Also, while the scanner is connected to my device, the keyboard does not show up on the screen, this problem goes away if I disconnect the scanner. My scanner model is CHS 7Pi Gray. And the iOS device I am using is iPAD mini 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is only populated into the selected field and the keyboard does not show up while the scanner is connected, the scanner is still in keyboard mode. While in keyboard mode, ScanAPI cannot connect to your scanner, configure it or notify your application of decoded data.

Consult the documentation that came with your scanner for instructions on putting it in "app mode".

*Note*: App mode for iOS is different than app mode for Android/Windows.